# How to begin UX writing for any project?

Tags: ux-writing

I work as a UX writer and I am trying to understand what steps a UX writer must follow before beginning a UX writing project.

At present, I talk to stakeholders first, conduct independent research, analyse, content design and lastly the audit.

A lot of times I work on work in progress screens and if suddenly the flow changes the UX writing also changes. Should I work on finalised screens or keep working on work in progress screens?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have two scenarios here. One that considers work in progress (WIP) and another that has you working over finished work.

Both scenarios are possible, and neither is wrong. I know that many people (probably most) like to work on finished versions, but working on WIP is a way to discover possibilities and pain points. Also: technically, there is no end to research, and it is possible that a "finished" screen will change the research results once you add your part.

Either way, if you want a more structured approach, do not work on UX Writing until after the [mockup phase](https://uxplanet.org/wireframe-mockup-prototype-what-is-what-8cf2966e5a8b). On the other hand, if your content changes something (and believe me, it will), then the mockup or prototype will need to be retested, so it's kind of a chicken-and-egg problem